# how to generate range date from date string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, range

I have a format of date as the below picture:

```
    {
      "amount": 599400,
      "date_cart_closed": "2015-03"
    },
    {
      "amount": 575856,
      "date_cart_closed": "2015-01"
    },
    {
      "amount": 2216490,
      "date_cart_closed": "2015-05"
    }
```

Here we have format like `2015-03`. The base date is fixed starting from `2011-01-01` until the date user enters in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` like `1343287040`.

Now the question is I have the start date and end date. In this range I have to fill gaps. To put it simple I don't have `2011-01`, `2011-02`, `2015-03` etc. How to fill these gaps? is there a way to handle this situation?

---

**EDIT1:**
It seems `pandas` create a range date based on month. I did the below for generating month:

```
pandas.date_range(start='20140101', end='20140501', freq='M')
```

Its output is as below:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-31', '2014-02-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M', tz=None)
```

It somehow solved my problem, but I need the output like: `2014-01` rather than `2014-01-01`. Is there a way to format output?

Comment: You could have just posted the *text* rather than an image of the text.

Comment: Just parse out the date into a Python `datetime.datetime` object; that's answered elsewhere, then use my solution from the duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the question you referred me to cannot be used for monthly date generation. As timedelta take `days` argument and I don't know the month is 31 days or 29 days.

Comment: Ah, missed you had no day component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one-liner. You can use `numpy.astype('<M8[M]')` to cast datetime object to monthly frequency and then `.astype(str)` to get the unicode string. This operation is vectorized and is very fast for large dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample datetime index
# ================================
ts_index = pd.date_range(start='20140101', end='20140501', freq='M')
ts_index

DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-31', '2014-02-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M', tz=None)

# processing
# ===================================
ts_index.values.astype('<M8[M]').astype(str)

array(['2014-01', '2014-02', '2014-03', '2014-04'], 
      dtype='<U25')
```

Comment: What does `<M8[M]` do?

Comment: @phpGeek `<M8[]` is the `numpy.datetime64` data type and `M` inside `[]` specifies the monthly frequency. daily frequency can be specified as `<M8[D]` and nano second frequency is `<M8[ns]`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your dates to an integer, in the number of months since the year 0:

```
def yearmonth_to_ordinal(date_string):
    year, month = map(int, date_string.split('-'))
    return year * 12 + (month - 1)
```

So 2015-01 becomes 24180, 2015-03 is 24182, etc. You can now create a range over the ordinal.

To go back to a date string, use modular arithmetic:

```
def ordinal_to_yearmonth(ordinal):
    year, month = divmod(ordinal, 12)
    return '{:04d}-{:02d}'.format(year, month + 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> yearmonth_to_ordinal('2015-05')
24184
>>> ordinal_to_yearmonth(yearmonth_to_ordinal('2015-05') + 7)
'2015-12'
```